# Python imports a different version of the library

Tags: python, scikit-learn, import, pip, version

I am trying to import scikit-learn version 1.1.2 from my environment, however it imports another version (0.24.2) when I try.

The code is below:

```
import sklearn 
print(sklearn.__version__)
-------
output: 0.24.2
```

I checked my environment from both pip commands and site-packages. I have the 1.1.2 version of scikit-learn. Tried to uninstall and install it again, doesn't work. When 1.1.2 version is not installed, python still imports 0.24.2 version from somewhere else I think.

How to import 1.1.2 version, and delete 0.24.2 version if I don't need it?

Also, how will I know if I need that 0.24.2 version?

Comment: Can you show the output for `python -m pip show sklearn`?

Comment: Here it is for sklearn:

`python -m pip show sklearn
output: WARNING: Package(s) not found: sklearn`

Here it is for scikit-learn:
`python -m pip show scikit-learn
Name: scikit-learn
Version: 1.1.2 ... (keeps going)`

Comment: I restarted my kernel and it is fixed. Now, I can import 1.1.2 version. I should have probably restart my kernel if I installed any libraries. Thanks a lot though Numan.

Comment: I posted it, will accept after 20 hours. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my kernel and it is fixed. Now, I can import 1.1.2 version. I should have probably restart my kernel if I installed any libraries.